# Is there a button to show documentation for the element under cursor in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: documentation, intellij-idea, javadoc, scaladoc

Some times it would be handy to see a ScalaDoc/JavaDoc page for the type of the element under cursor. Surprisingly, I could find no IDE-built-in way to do this (despite the fact the most of the libraries I use are accompanied by documentation and source jars). Is it there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `View -> Quick Documentation` (Default shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>)
or you can display Javadoc in browser with `View -> External Documentation` (Default shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>)

Comment: On Mac, default key mapping is `Ctrl + J` to show Quick Documentation.

Comment: I am able to see the external documentation for Java, but not for Scala (there is no option for `External Documentation` when the editor cursor is on a Scala class or method). Would you know how to fix that?